# Reducing MongoDB latency

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My NodeJS server used to connect to my remote MongoDB instance using the older syntax in version "mongodb": "^2.2.33". However after I updated the syntax for the new version 3.1.3, the data fetching seems to be significantly slower. It seems that the authentication/ retrieving client for the connection is taking a much longer time than before. Has anyone faced this before? Any recommendations for this?

MONGODB_HOST variable below is of the format: [username:password@IP_address]

BEFORE (for version 2.2.33):

```
mongoClient.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_HOST}:27017/test`, function(err, db){
    console.log("Mongo client connected");
    db.collection('data')
        .find({ ... })
        .sort({ time: 1 })
        .toArray(function(err, items){
            console.log(items);
            db.close();
        }
});
```

AFTER (version 3.1.3):

```
mongoClient.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_HOST}:27017/test`, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        const db = client.db('data');
        db.collection(collection)
            .find(query)   // query parameters in JSON object
                .sort({ time: 1 })
                .toArray(function (err, items) {
                    console.log(items);
                    client.close();
                 });
});
```

**EDITED:**
After using console.time to measure the latency a few times, turns out that actually both versions are equally slow. For e.g. connection time is about 2700ms whereas fetching only ~1 hour's data (~2593 records) from a remote MongoDB server (including connecting and authenticating) takes about 6800ms. Am still actively looking for approaches on how to reduce this latency, either on MongoDB, or even open to changing out to a (low-cost) low latency NoSQL DB, thanks!

Comment: what is the structure of the data, and it's indexes?

Comment: These are time-series data so something like: { device: 12345, time: "2018-08-20T00:00:00.000Z", value: 20, _id: 12345152304800000} where index uses the device_id concatenated with unix timestamp.